# How can I fix my dependancy error in Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx

I currently have 2 packages that package API depends on Package base_code.  In base_code I keep many classes that are used by other packages.  I have changed a procedure in the base_code package and created a new version, simularly I have changed the API package to fit the new procedure structure and created a new version.

However now I find that I cannot release the base_code package first because the it causes the existing code in the API package to raise a compile failure.  Obviously I cannot release the API package first either, how am I supposed to manage this?  Am I not expected to refactor procedures between packages that have dependencies?  I feel like Im missing something fundemental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer to this, you can use the advanced Options on the package install screen to compile only the apex in the package.

Well done me :)